# How to find the touch point of PDF present in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I am working on document based application. I will load the PDF in UIWebView. For my requirement, i have to add an image in my touch/tap point. I have found the touch point(CGPoint) in UIWebview. But i want to get the same touch point of PDF that was loaded in PDF.

In detail, UIWebView show the contents of PDF document in varied size(Small size). So the touchpoint(CGPoint) of UIWebView will differ with the PDF.

[image]  [image]

I am not rendering the content of UIWebView to PDF due to decrease in page clarity. I will render the content of PDF directly.

Below code will explain the how i am rendering the PDF.

Code for PDF render:

```
NSString *tessdataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"input" ofType:@"pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tessdataPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);

const size_t numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);

for(size_t page = 1; page <= numberOfPages; page++)
{
    //  Get the current page and page frame
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, page);
    const CGRect pageFrame = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);

    //  Draw the page (flipped)
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    if(page == 1)
    {
        for (UIView *subview in [self.pdfView.scrollView subviews]) {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)subview;
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
                CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(img.frame.origin.x, img.frame.origin.y);
                [self drawCustomPDFContent:img.image point1:point1];
            }
        }
    }
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
pdf = nil;

NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.pdf"];
//bool fileCopied = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtURL:url toURL:toUrl error:nil];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

In this, i am rendering the input pdf with an image in page 1. Image was successfully rendered with input.pdf. But i need to add the image at exact point in pdf. See the above image for touch point difference. Can anyone provide the solution to find the exact touch point in PDF?